# Windows phone 7.0 vs 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does windows phone **7.5** support windows phone **7.0** apps. can we run the application on windows phone **7.5** if it is built in windows phone **7.0** and vice verse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows Phone 7.5 can run Windows Phone 7.0 apps, however as all devices should now be running Windows Phone 7.5 then you should create Windows Phone 7.5 apps from the outset.

Comment: Thanks for reply 
Can we run 7.5 app in 7.0?

Comment: No this is not possible, also a recent change has now been included which prevents access to the Marketplace unless you are running Windows Phone 7.5 : http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/05/22/starting-today-you-need-windows-phone-7-5-to-use-marketplace.aspx